# Simple alternative to current serverless environments providers

Tags: web-development, node.js, web-server, amazon

I'm looking for an approachable alternative to the current serverless platforms. I've put my hands in AWS Lambda and GCP Cloud Functions, and even if I get the job done, it's a pain to use everytime, be it the complex CLI tools, the IAM management or the hardships encountered when trying to build a decent pipeline, with different environments. So I'm looking for any kind of provider, giving me access to :

- serverless functions
- NoSQL database
- message queue system (like GCP Pub/Sub)
- file storage

And making all of it easier to access. I'm a freelance developer working alone, and the environments provided by Google, Amazon or Microsoft start to feel way too enterprise-sized to work correctly with.

During my search I've stumbled upon Netlify which seems to be a good solution, but I haven't tried it yet. Vercel seems to go in the same direction, but it looks like it's not made to run long functions at all.

After further research : Render looks like a very accessible contender, but it's not really serverless anymore, especially on the scaling part.